# How to show That T is not compact

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

how to show that the operator $T(t)$ defined on $\mathbb{X}= \left\{ u \in \mathbf{C}\left(\mathbb{R}\right): \lim\limits_{ x \rightarrow \pm \infty} u(x) = 0\right\}$ endowed with the norm $$\|u\|_{\infty} = \sup_{-\infty <x<+\infty} |u(x)|$$ by :

$T(t)f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{|x-y|^{2}}{4t}}f(y) \, dy$.     $(t >0)$

is not compact ?

I can't build a suitable sequence $(\varphi_{n})_{n}$ such that  $T(\varphi_{n})(x)$ diverges on $\mathbb {X}$

Comment: What have you tried[??](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: What do you mean by $\overline{ \mathbb{R} }$?

Comment: just $\mathbb {R}$

Comment: @KricheMuhamed, what is the meaning of the parameter $t$? So, try using the Fourier transform to show that this operator is isometrically equivalent to the operator of multiplication by a function. Therefore, it is not compact.

Comment: You need a different norm or a different $X$; there exist $f\in X$ with $||f||_\infty=\infty$.

Comment: Also  the integral defining $Tf$ need not exist for $f\in X$...

Comment: The norm is fine, as he is working with continuous functions the condition  $\lim _{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} u(x)=0$ guarantees that doesn't exist $u$ such that $\|u\|_{\infty} = \infty$.